# Replace invalid XML unicode sequence in a string C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, xml-parsing

Looking for a function in C++ which is a counterpart to `Character.isIdentifierIgnorable()` in Java. Basically I have to replace them with another string derived from them (so that information is not lost).

My implementation in Java:

```
public static String replaceInvalidChar (String s) {
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

     char[] characters = s.toCharArray();

     for (char c : characters) {
             if (Character.isIdentifierIgnorable(c)){
                     sb.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int)c));
             } else {
                     sb.append(c);
             }
     }

     return sb.toString();
}
```

Aiming to do the same in C++, but in order to replace the character I need to detect them first. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Looks like `std::iswctrl` and `std::iswspace` may cover it after converting `utf8` to `UCS2/UTF16` wise strings.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather about how `Character.isIdentifierIgnorable()` works something along these lines may work for you:

```
std::wstring replaceInvalidChar(std::wstring const& s)
{
    std::wostringstream sb;

    for(auto c: s)
    {
        if(std::iswcntrl(c) && !std::iswspace(c))
            sb << L"\\u" << std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill(L'0') << int(c);
        else
            sb << wchar_t(c);
    }

    return sb.str();
}
```

Comment: It misses out on '\u0000', but works for '\u001b'. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @SauravSahu How are you initializing the string that contains `\u0000`? (some constructors end the string before the `null` character (`\u0000`). For example you can use `std::wstring s{L"hello\u001b \0 \t \n \4d\5y ", 18};`

Comment: In Java https://www.ideone.com/E5IFPN, I am able to parse till the end, but not in CPP https://www.ideone.com/i0ozyo.

Comment: @SauravSahu Yes because the `null` character terminates the string when it is used to initialize it. You need to use a constructor that specifies its length like this: https://www.ideone.com/SYfjHT

Comment: @SauravSahu If you want to use syntax that is more similar to `Java` (but still not the same) you can initialize the `std::wstring` using a `std::wstring` by adding `s` as a suffix to the string literal and `using std::literals` like this: https://www.ideone.com/Ls50Pi

Answer (score 0):

Per Java's [`Character.isIdentifierIgnorable(char)` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable(char)):

> Determines if the specified character should be regarded as an ignorable character in a Java identifier or a Unicode identifier.
>
> The following Unicode characters are ignorable in a Java identifier or a Unicode identifier:
>
> - ISO control characters that are not whitespace
>
>   - '\u0000' through '\u0008'
>   - '\u000E' through '\u001B'
>   - '\u007F' through '\u009F'
> - all characters that have the FORMAT general category value
>
> **Note**: This method cannot handle [supplementary characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#supplementary). To support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the [`isIdentifierIgnorable(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isIdentifierIgnorable(int)) method
>
> **Parameters**:
>       ch - the character to be tested.
>
> **Returns**:
>       `true` if the character is an ignorable control character that may be part of a Java or Unicode identifier; `false` otherwise.

So, try something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

bool isFormatChar(wchar_t ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case 0x00AD:

        case 0x2028:
        case 0x2029:

        case 0x061C:
        case 0x200E:
        case 0x200F:
        case 0x202A:
        case 0x202B:
        case 0x202C:
        case 0x202D:
        case 0x202E:
        case 0x2066:
        case 0x2067:
        case 0x2068:
        case 0x2069:

            // and many many more! For the full list of Format chars, see:
            // http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm
            // http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zl/list.htm
            // http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zp/list.htm

            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

std::wstring replaceInvalidChar(const std::wstring &s)
{
    std::wostringstream sb;

    for (auto ch: s)
    {
        if (((ch >= 0x0000) && (ch <= 0x0008)) ||
            ((ch >= 0x000E) && (ch <= 0x001B)) ||
            ((ch >= 0x007F) && (ch <= 0x009F)) ||
            isFormatChar(ch))
        {
            sb << L"\\u" << std::hex << std::nouppercase << std::setw(4) << std::setfill(L'0') << int(ch);
        } 
        else
        {
            sb.put(ch);
        }
    }

    return sb.str();
}
```